# Issues with cvseq push and size in opencv using c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to write a simple C++ script using opencv to detect faces and save one facial square box for each new face showing up in the camera. The frame should be right, but I'm struggling with the pointer / esp. "total" around cvseq. Could someone help me? Whenever it gets to the row "cvSeqPush(faces_new, r);", faces_new shows up with 60 or 70 in the faces_new->total, without ever being allocated with anything.... Very frustrated, and would really appreciate some help.

```
// memeory allocation
static CvMemStorage* storage = 0;
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
static CvMemStorage* storage2 = 0;
storage2 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
static CvMemStorage* storage3 = 0;
storage3 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

// Create a new named window with title: result
cvNamedWindow("Window"); // create a window to display in
CvCapture* capture = capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1); // capture from video device (Macbook iSight)
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000 );// set window size to 640
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600 ); // set window size to 480

// Declare images
IplImage *imgCamera; // captured from camera
IplImage *imgCamera_last; // last campera image
IplImage *imgDrawn; // image with drawing (rect containing faces)
IplImage *imgFace; // face picture extracted from the camera
CvRect *r; // rects containing faces
CvSeq *faces = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvRect), storage); ; // sequnece of faces in the camera image - CURRENT
CvSeq *faces_last = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvRect), storage2); // sequnece of faces in the camera image - LAST FRAME
CvSeq *faces_new = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvRect), storage3); // sequnece of faces in the camera image - NEW FACES
float scale = 1.0/5; // how far do we want to scale down the haar detect objects images for speed

// Create a new Haar classifier
static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;
cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );

// file name where to save the file
std::stringstream filename;

int counter = 1;
int filecounter = 1;
while(1) {
    //*************************************************************************************/
    //Step 1: stream video. Video to images
    //*************************************************************************************/

    // capture frame from video and then turn it into one single image-imgCamera
    capture_frame(capture, imgCamera);

    // allocate an image to be used later
    imgDrawn = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgCamera), imgCamera->depth, imgCamera->nChannels);
    imgFace = cvCreateImage(cvSize(600, 600), imgCamera->depth, imgCamera->nChannels);
    cvCopy(imgCamera, imgDrawn);

    if (counter == 10) { // take action for every 10 frames

        counter = 1;
        //*************************************************************************************/
        //Step 2: Detection
        //*************************************************************************************/
        find_faces(imgCamera, storage, cascade, faces, scale);
        //printf("Last faces seq had %d faces detected. \n",faces_last->total);

        //*************************************************************************************/
        //Step 4: Draw every face in the picture
        //*************************************************************************************/

        // for each face found in the image
        for(int i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ ){
            // get the rect from the sequence
            r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);

            // draw the rectange around the face on the imgDrawn
            draw_rect(imgDrawn, r, scale);
        }

        cvShowImage("Window", imgDrawn);
        // press escape to quit
        if( cvWaitKey(33) == 27 ) break;
        //*************************************************************************************/
        //Step 3: Recognize the new faces
        //*************************************************************************************/
        //TO DO: Combined the following into a funciton: match_faces(faces_new, faces, faces_last, lastspotted, currentspotted, imgCamera);
        for(int i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ ){
            cout << "faces_new"<< faces_new->total<< "\n";
            // get the rect from the sequence
            r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);
            if (faces_last->total == 0) {
                //cout << "New PERSON!!";
                cvSeqPush(faces_new, r);
            }
            else {
                for(int k = 0; k < (faces_last ? faces_last->total : 0); k++ ){
                    CvRect *r_last = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces_last, k);
                    if (!same_face(r, r_last, imgCamera, imgCamera_last, i, k)) {
                        cvSeqPush(faces_new, r);
                        //cout << "faces_new"<< faces_new->total<< "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //*************************************************************************************/
        //Step 3: Process faces - save new faces, report new faces
        //*************************************************************************************/

        if ((faces_new->total)>0) {
            // To change to save only faces_new
            save_faces(faces_new, imgCamera, imgFace, scale, filecounter);
            // report_faces(filecounter, faces_new->total, model); // report new faces stored starting from filecounter
            filecounter = filecounter+(faces_new-> total);}

        cvClearMemStorage(storage2);
        cvSeqPush(faces_last, faces);
        //cout << "face_last:" << faces_last->total << "\n";}
        cvClearMemStorage(storage);
        cvClearMemStorage(storage3);
    }
    counter++;
    imgCamera_last = imgCamera;

}

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvReleaseImage(&imgCamera);
cvReleaseImage(&imgDrawn);
cvReleaseImage(&imgFace);
cvDestroyWindow("window");
```

Comment: use the c++ api instead ( where you'd get a proper `vector<Rect>` ). honestly, the c-api is deprecated and you should not use it any more

Comment: Thanks! Could have used vector... Figured it out myself, mostly memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it work.

```
// memeory allocation
static CvMemStorage* storage = 0;
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
static CvMemStorage* storage2 = 0;
storage2 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

// Create a new named window with title: result
cvNamedWindow("Window"); // create a window to display in
CvCapture* capture = capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1); // capture from video device (Macbook iSight)
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000 );// set window size to 640
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600 ); // set window size to 480

// Declare images
IplImage *imgCamera; // captured from camera
IplImage *imgCamera_last; // last campera image
IplImage *imgDrawn; // image with drawing (rect containing faces)
IplImage *imgFace; // face picture extracted from the camera
CvRect *r; // rects containing faces
CvSeq *faces = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvRect), storage); ; // sequnece of faces in the camera image - CURRENT
CvSeq *faces_last = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvRect), storage2); // sequnece of faces in the camera image - LAST FRAME
float scale = 1.0/5; // how far do we want to scale down the haar detect objects images for speed

// Create a new Haar classifier
static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;
cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );

// file name where to save the file
std::stringstream filename;

int counter = 1;
int filecounter = 1;
while(1) {
    //*************************************************************************************/
    //Step 1: stream video. Video to images
    //*************************************************************************************/

    // capture frame from video and then turn it into one single image-imgCamera
    capture_frame(capture, imgCamera);

    // allocate an image to be used later
    imgDrawn = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgCamera), imgCamera->depth, imgCamera->nChannels);
    imgFace = cvCreateImage(cvSize(600, 600), imgCamera->depth, imgCamera->nChannels);
    cvCopy(imgCamera, imgDrawn);

    if (counter == 10) { // take action for every 10 frames

        counter = 1;
        //*************************************************************************************/
        //Step 2: Detection
        //*************************************************************************************/
        find_faces(imgCamera, storage, cascade, faces, scale);
        //printf("Last faces seq had %d faces detected. \n",faces_last->total);

        //*************************************************************************************/
        //Step 4: Draw every face in the picture
        //*************************************************************************************/

        // for each face found in the image
        for(int i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ ){
            // get the rect from the sequence
            r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);

            // draw the rectange around the face on the imgDrawn
            draw_rect(imgDrawn, r, scale);
        }

        cvShowImage("Window", imgDrawn);
        // press escape to quit
        if( cvWaitKey(33) == 27 ) break;
        //*************************************************************************************/
        //Step 3: Recognize the new faces
        //*************************************************************************************/
        //TO DO: Combined the following into a funciton: match_faces(faces_new, faces, faces_last, lastspotted, currentspotted, imgCamera);
        for(int i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ ){
            // get the rect from the sequence
            r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);
            if (faces_last->total == 0) {
                cout<<"a face appeared: "<<"there are total faces of "<<faces_last->total<<"\n";
                save_face(r, imgCamera, imgFace, scale, filecounter);
                filecounter++;
                //report_faces(filecounter, faces_new->total, model); // report new faces stored starting from filecounter
            }
            else {
                for(int k = 0; k < (faces_last ? faces_last->total : 0); k++ ){
                    CvRect *r_last = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces_last, k);
                    if (!same_face(r, r_last, imgCamera, imgCamera_last, i, k)) {
                        save_face(r, imgCamera, imgFace, scale, filecounter);
                        filecounter++;
                        //report_faces(filecounter, faces_new->total, model); // report new faces stored starting from filecounter
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //cvClearMemStorage(storage2);
        while (faces_last->total >0) {
            cvSeqPop(faces_last);}

        for(int i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ ){
            // get the rect from the sequence
            r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);
            cvSeqPush(faces_last, r);
        }
        //cout << "face_last:" << faces_last->total << "\n";}
        cvClearMemStorage(storage);
    }
    counter++;
    imgCamera_last = imgCamera;

}

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvReleaseImage(&imgCamera);
cvReleaseImage(&imgDrawn);
cvReleaseImage(&imgFace);
cvDestroyWindow("window");

// return 0 to indicate successfull execution of the program
return 0;
```